# How to convert string to type defined by an abi.Type for payload construction?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, abi, golang, data-types

I am writing a CLI in Go that should faciliate users to be able to make contract function calls from it. This entails generating contract ABIs and providing input parameters to the function arguments but requires knowledge of the argument type to be able to construct a transaction payload correctly. This payload becomes the data component of an Ethereum transaction to make a function call.

My CLI prompts for input which then needs to be converted to a specific type for that parameter as defined by its ABI.

```
// Compile solidity contract given a path to file
contract, err := compiler.CompileSolidity("", contractPath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ERROR failed to compile contract:", err)
}

path := strings.Split(contractPath, "/")
contractName := path[len(path)-1]

// Resulting compiled contract instance
compiledContract = contract[contractPath+":"+strings.Replace(contractName, ".sol", "", -1)]

// Retrieve the ABI definition as a JSON string from the compiled contract
abiStr, err := json.Marshal(compiledContract.Info.AbiDefinition)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ERROR marshalling abi to string", err)
}

// Go format ABI from JSON
abiContract, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(string(abiStr)))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ERROR reading contract ABI ", err)
}

inputParameters := abi.Methods[methodName].Inputs
// Gets input parameters to named method as strings
args := getArguments(inputParameters)

payload, err := abiContract.Pack(methodName, args...)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ERROR packing the method name for the contract call: ", err)
}
```

As shown above, a contract instance is compiled and its generated ABI used to discern the method metadata. For a given `methodName`, a `Method` contains `Inputs` as type `Arguments` which contain information for each input argument including parameter name and type. This code is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/96fd50be10885c9b3033404df698177fdb63d036/accounts/abi/argument.go).

Above, `args` is an array of `string` that have been input as parameters to the `methodName` function call but need to be casted to the correct type before `abiContract.Pack` where it panics due to type mismatch of provided parameters vs the expected type as defined by the ABI.

Given a variable of type `string` and another variable of type [`abi.Type`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/461291882edce0ac4a28f64c4e8725b7f57cbeae/accounts/abi/type.go#L44) how can I perform a type conversion to convert the `string` variable into the type defined by the `abi.Type` variable?

Answer (score 0):

`abi.Pack` rest arguments must be of type `interface{}` so create an `[]interface{}` to hold your values in order to spread them:

```
args := []string{"foo"}
var iargs []interface{}
for _, arg := range args {
    iargs = append(iargs, args)
}

packed, err := abiContract.Pack(methodName, iargs...)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(packed)
```

Here's a full example demonstrating how to use `Pack` and `Unpack`:

`Store.sol` (example smart contract)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Store {
  mapping (bytes32 => bytes32) public items;

  function setItem(bytes32 key, bytes32 value) external {
    items[key] = value;
  }
}
```

`main.go` (full example code)

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    ethereum "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"

    store "./contracts" // where the abigen compiled contract is
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rinkeby.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    abiContract, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(string(store.StoreABI)))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var key [32]byte
    copy(key[:], []byte("foo"))
    iargs := []interface{}{key}

    packed, err := abiContract.Pack("items", iargs...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(packed) // [72 243 67 243 102 111 111 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

    contractAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x147b8eb97fd247d06c4006d269c90c1908fb5d54")

    msg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        To:   &contractAddress,
        Data: packed,
    }

    output, err := client.CallContract(context.Background(), msg, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var item [32]byte
    err = abiContract.Unpack(&item, "items", output)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(item[:])) // "bar"
}
```

Comment: Your variable is already of type `[32]byte` which would only satisfy the `Pack` call in this case. The problem in itself is being able to assert, given the variable in some other type, the type that is required for the `Pack` function. In these cases it seems that for required types such as `bytes32[]` or `bytes2[5]`, or 2D arrays, it seems impossible to convert a variable from any other type to the required type _in general_ where we need to be able to handle `bytesn[m]` without hard coding 2^256 different permutations of byte arrays: `bytes1[1]`, `bytes1[2]`,... `bytes32[254]`,`bytes32[255]`